# how can restrict traffic between nodes in kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to block traffic between nodes in kubernetes.

This is because i don't want to have any effect on the traffic coming from the specfic pod.

how can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use network policies for this. The following example of a network policy blocks all in-cluster traffic to a set of web server pods, except the pods allowed by the policy configuration.

To achieve this setup, create a NetworkPolicy with the following manifest:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: foo
```

Once you apply this configuration, only pods with label

> app: foo

can talk to the pods with the label

> app: nginx.

Comment: this will not work if we use eks and aws vpc cni